# CSOM: WorkflowInteropService is returned null

Tags: workflow, csom

I'm trying to run SP2010 workflow in SP2013 portal and stuck on the nullable interop service...

The following powershell script returns $interopService.ServerObjectIsNull == false, but when it's run in my other test environment it always returns true. Any ideas on the causes and what can I check?

```
$spContext = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://portal")
$web = $spContext.Web
$spContext.Load($web)
$spContext.ExecuteQuery()
$wfMngr = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($spcontext, $web)
$interopService  = $wfMngr.GetWorkflowInteropService()
$spcontext.ExecuteQuery()
$interopService.ServerObjectIsNull
```

Comment: Can it be due to Workflow Manager is not installed in my portal?

Comment: Ok, resolved the problem by installing Workflow Manager.